# ScalaJS - SBT crossproject configuration for testing part of the `JS`-module on the JVM

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

The `build.sbt` below is for a project where there 3 modules:

1. `Shared`-module

   - compiles to the JS-platform and to the JVM-platform
   - visible to the `JVM` module, to the `JS` module and to itself
2. `JVM`-module

   - compiles to JVM-platform,
   - not visible to `JS`-module, nor to `Shared`-module, only visible to itself
3. `JS`-module

   - compiles to JS-platform
   - not visible to `JVM`-module, nor to `Shared`-module, only visible to itself

I would like to have a fourth module `TestJSonJVM` which compiles to both the JVM-platform and to the JS-platform and it is visible only to the `JS`-module and to itself.

The purpose of the `TestJSonJVM`-module is to extract part of the `JS`-modul's logic/code into `TestJSonJVM`-module which makes it possible to test the extracted part on the JVM-platform (which has better tooling - (debuging, IDE integration, etc..) than the JS-platform for ScalaJS).

How do I need to modify the `build.sbt` file below ? Such that this becomes possible ?

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(imJS, imJVM)
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := Settings.versions.scala,
    publish := {},
    publishLocal := {}
  )

lazy val im = crossProject
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Settings.sharedDependencies.value,
    addCompilerPlugin(
      "org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full),
    scalaVersion := Settings.versions.scala,
    name := "im",
    version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  )
  .jvmSettings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Settings.jvmDependencies.value,
    mainClass in Test := Some("app.server.rest.TestHttpServerApp"),
    mainClass in Compile := Some("app.server.rest.TestHttpServerApp")
  )
  .jsSettings(
    mainClass in Compile := Some("app.client.Main"),
    libraryDependencies ++= Settings.scalajsDependencies.value,
    persistLauncher in Compile := true,
    persistLauncher in Test := false,
    jsDependencies += RuntimeDOM,
    scalaJSOptimizerOptions ~= { _.withDisableOptimizer(true) }
    )

lazy val imJVM = im.jvm
lazy val imJS = im.js

persistLauncher in Compile := true

persistLauncher in Test := false

cancelable in Global := true
```

Comment: You say that you have 3 modules, but I only see 2: `imJVM` and `imJS`. `shared` is not a module; it is just a directory containing source files. In fact you are probably already mistaken in your assumption that your JVM-module is not visible to your Shared-module. It is, and so is your JS-module.

Comment: Hmm... thanks, but `imJS` is not visible from `imJVM` and vica versa right ? If `imJS` is visible to `shared` and `X` in shared uses `Z` from `imJS` and `Y` from `imJVM` uses `X`, then `Y` from `imJVM` uses `Z` from `imJS` ? So `imJVM`  depends on `imJS` ?

Comment: I may have been unclear. There *is no* `shared` module. There is only `imJVM` and `imJS`. To build `imJVM`, we take all the sources in both `shared/` and `jvm/`, and we compile them *together*. Therefore, in the context of `imJVM`, sources in `jvm/` and in `shared/` see each other. Similarly, in the context of `imJS`, sources in `js/` and in `shared/` see each other and are compiled together to form the `imJS` module.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting ! But then what happens when compiling `js/` and the source in `shared/` wants something that only exist in `jvm/` ?

Comment: Compile error, obviously.